Remove O/P without complete session and not the duplicates
def prepare_data(df):
    entry_df = df[df['Direction'] == 'enter'][['vrm', 'Direction']]
    entry_df.columns = ['vrm', 'Entry_Direction']

    exit_df = df[df['Direction'] == 'leave'][['vrm', 'Direction']]
    exit_df.columns = ['vrm', 'Exit_Direction']

    merged_df = pd.merge(entry_df, exit_df, on='vrm', how='outer')
    return merged_df


prepared_data1 = prepare_data(ncp)
prepared_data2 = prepare_data(taskle)

final_df = pd.merge(prepared_data1, prepared_data2, on='vrm', how='inner', suffixes=('_ncp', '_taskle'))
final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['vrm']).reset_index(drop=True)

I was using drop duplicates but I want to show the ones having more than one session (one session is one entry and one exit).
If Ram has two entries and exists in both the dataframes, the output should be like:-
vrm Entry_Direction_ncp Exit_Direction_ncp Entry_Direction_taskle Exit_Direction_taskle  
0   Sita                enter              leave                  enter                   leave   
1   Ram                 enter              leave                  enter                   leave   
2   Ram                 enter              leave                  enter                   leave  

